# Getting shortcode with multiple attributes

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, shortcode

I want to create `shortcode` with multiple attributes.
But I am only able to do with single not multiple attributes.

I am able only this :

```
add_shortcode('test','get_shortcode');
```

But I want to create `shortcode` like this :

```
add_shortcode('test id=1 title=test','get_shortcode');
```

and I would like to call this `shortcode` in my page like this.

```
do_shortcode('[test id="1" title="test"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello add in your functions $atts like that

```
function bartag_func( $atts ) {
$atts = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'foo' => 'no foo',
        'bar' => 'default bar',
    ), $atts, 'bartag' );

return 'bartag: ' . $atts['foo'] . ' ' . $atts['bar'];
}

add_shortcode( 'bartag', 'bartag_func' );
```

It's display result like `[bartag foo="koala" bar="bears"]`